# How to install MySql 32 bit on Mac OS 64 bit?

Tags: mysql, macos, wxpython

The wxPython package must run in 32 bit mode, but the official MySql download page does not have any link to download the 32bit installer. Do you know where to download the 32bit installer of MySql?

Thanks

[image]

---

UPDATE: I am trying to download MySql 32 bit for Mac.

### [image]

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect. The Cocoa build of wxPython supports both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. From the wxPython [downloads](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) page:

`The file with "cocoa" in the name use the Cocoa API for implementing the GUI, requires at least OSX 10.5, and supports either 32-bit or 64-bit architectures.`

The Carbon builds are built for i386 and PPC.

Also note that if you go into the Development Releases tab on the MySQL downloads page, it has 32-bit tars and dmgs

Comment: You are correct about wxPython being available in 32bit. But when launch Robot testing framework, I am getting the error:
    python should be executed in 32-bit mode to support wxPython on mac. Check BUILD.rest for details

Do you have any insight about why there is such a constraint?

Comment: Can you please share a direct link to the Development Releases tab? Or can you upload a screenshot highlighting the tab? I am having troubles locating a 32bit tar on the Mysql Download page.  Thanks

Comment: Now I can find it under Archives.